# Using colorbox with media files

Tags: 7, wysiwyg, media, javascript

The components I am using are:

- CKEditor 3.6.6.1
- Media 7.x.2.x-dev
- Media Colorbox 7.x-1.0-rc4
- Colorbox 7.x-2.4
- Panels 7.x.3.3

The Theme I am using is: Bootstrap 7.x-2.2

I am trying to figure out how when I insert an image via the WYSIWYG editor CKEditor to have the image be smaller then be able to be opened in a colorbox. I am currently using the above modules with this process:

1. Create a new article
2. Click insert media
3. Click Library
4. Click a preloaded image I already have selected
5. Display as Colorbox
6. Click submit
7. Save the content

After all of that nothing happens. The image is not clickable at all (as to mean that a pointer does not render when I move my mouse over the image). What I am asking is simple. I have read that Media should handle colorbox integration now for images... how? I want to be able to insert images via the WYSIWYG but cannot seem to find instructions on this matter.

Answer (score 1):

Did you customize this page: http://yoursite.com/admin/config/media/file-types/manage/image/file-display/colorbox ?

You should select a display mode for thumbnail (small image) and Colorbox (full size image).
Once you have updated this, clear caches or edit your content and save it again. Otherwise, your changes won't have any effect.